# Multiple AlgorithmSuite Policies WS-SecurityPolicy CXF

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf, ws-security, wss4j

When defining multiple policies in an AlgorithmSuite in a WSDL I get an exception.

```
<sp:AlgorithmSuite>
    <wsp:Policy>
        <sp:Basic128Rsa15/>
        <sp:Basic256Rsa15/>
        <sp:TripleDesRsa15/>
    </wsp:Policy>
</sp:AlgorithmSuite>
```

Exception:

```
2016-05-04 12:49:52,393 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.wsdl11.Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider] (default task-3) Failed to build the policy 'X509EndpointPolicy':Invalid Policy
2016-05-04 12:49:52,398 FINE  [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (default task-3) Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyInInterceptor@44076866
2016-05-04 12:49:52,398 FINE  [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (default task-3) Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.configuration.SecurityProviderConfig$Interceptor@cd2ca8f
2016-05-04 12:49:52,399 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (default task-3) Interceptor for {http://logius.nl/digipoort/wus/2.0/aanleverservice/1.2/}AanleverService_V1_2 has thrown exception, unwinding now: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Policy
    at org.apache.wss4j.policy.model.AlgorithmSuite.parseNestedPolicy(AlgorithmSuite.java:494)
    at org.apache.wss4j.policy.model.AlgorithmSuite.<init>(AlgorithmSuite.java:448)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.custom.DefaultAlgorithmSuiteLoader$GCMAlgorithmSuite.<init>(DefaultAlgorithmSuiteLoader.java:118)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.custom.DefaultAlgorithmSuiteLoader.getAlgorithmSuite(DefaultAlgorithmSuiteLoader.java:68)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.custom.AlgorithmSuiteBuilder.build(AlgorithmSuiteBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.custom.AlgorithmSuiteBuilder.build(AlgorithmSuiteBuilder.java:37)
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.invokeBuilder(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:138)
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.build(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:117)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:224)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicyOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:174)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicy(PolicyBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.wss4j.policy.builders.AsymmetricBindingBuilder.build(AsymmetricBindingBuilder.java:44)
    at org.apache.wss4j.policy.builders.AsymmetricBindingBuilder.build(AsymmetricBindingBuilder.java:34)
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.invokeBuilder(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:138)
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.build(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:117)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:224)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getAllOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:184)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:217)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getExactlyOneOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:180)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:215)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicyOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:174)
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicy(PolicyBuilder.java:124)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.reference.LocalServiceModelReferenceResolver.resolveReference(LocalServiceModelReferenceResolver.java:53)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.wsdl11.Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.resolveLocal(Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.java:292)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.wsdl11.Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.resolveReference(Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.wsdl11.Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.getElementPolicy(Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.java:220)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.wsdl11.Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.getElementPolicy(Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.java:168)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.wsdl11.Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.getElementPolicy(Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.java:161)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.wsdl11.Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.getEffectivePolicy(Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider.java:98)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngineImpl.getAggregatedEndpointPolicy(PolicyEngineImpl.java:451)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.EndpointPolicyImpl.initializePolicy(EndpointPolicyImpl.java:152)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.EndpointPolicyImpl.initialize(EndpointPolicyImpl.java:140)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngineImpl.createEndpointPolicyInfo(PolicyEngineImpl.java:584)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngineImpl.getEndpointPolicy(PolicyEngineImpl.java:313)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngineImpl.getServerEndpointPolicy(PolicyEngineImpl.java:299)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyInInterceptor.handle(PolicyInInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AbstractPolicyInterceptor.handleMessage(AbstractPolicyInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:108)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:134)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:217)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:136)
    at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When I define one of the policies it works fine.

```
<sp:AlgorithmSuite>
    <wsp:Policy>
        <sp:Basic256Rsa15/>
    </wsp:Policy>
</sp:AlgorithmSuite>
```

The given WSDL: http://pastebin.com/mmZdiwYL

Is the notation for the policies in the AlgorithmSuite valid?

In org.apache.wss4j.policy.model.AlgorithmSuite the policies are process. After processing the first policy successfully, an exception is thrown at line 494 during the process of the second policy. Because an algorithmSuiteType is already set during processing the first policy, the check if algorithmSuiteType is null fails.

I am using Wildfly 10.

Comment: How did you solve the issue?

Comment: I did not. When I define one policy it works fine, but still hoping to get a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to put the algorithms inside the `<wsp:ExactlyOne>` tags. That what made it work for me:

```
<sp:AlgorithmSuite>
  <wsp:Policy>
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <sp:Basic256Rsa15 />
      <sp:TripleDesRsa15/>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
</sp:AlgorithmSuite>
```